# Access to the path 'C:\Users\amministratore\Documents\pippo.xml' is denied

Tags: c#, xamarin

I wrote the following code with VS2017 in xamarin.forms on win10:

```
File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "pippo.xml"));
```

why I always get the error?

> Access to the path 'C:\Users\amministratore\Documents\pippo.xml' is
>   denied.

I run VS as administrator and set permision in manifest.
Tanks!

Comment: Can you check the permission on the target file ? Can you open this file in Notepad (for example) ?

Comment: Is it working if you try to read from a different drive (not OS)?

Comment: What is the windows OS you have on the machine ?

Comment: yes I have access to the file with other programs (notepad, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you run your program/IDE as Administrator to access that folder. This issue will appear if you have no permission .

In windows (UWP),In addition to the default locations, an app can access additional files and folders by declaring capabilities in the app manifest (see App capability declarations), or by calling a file picker to let the user pick files and folders for the app to access (see Open files and folders with a picker).

You can use **[broadFileSystemAccess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions#accessing-additional-locations)** then go to **Start** , and then **select > Settings  > Privacy > File system**.
Make sure allow apps to access your file system is turned On.